# New python 3.6 venv giving error on MacOS

Tags: python, anaconda, python-venv

I have a python 3.5.2 anaconda installation on MacOS v10.11.

```
$ which python
/Users/<username>/anaconda3/bin/python
```

If I try to run python command to build a virtual env in the same directory

```
py-venv $ python -m venv /Users/<username>/workarea/py-venv
Error: Command '['/Users/<username>/workarea/py-venv/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Then it complains with the error mentioned above. The same error occurs if I use the same commands with `python3` instead of `python`.
Any clues?

Comment: honestly, if you are using anaconda to begin with, I'd just use the conda create command to manage virtual environments. It gives more flexibility/compatibility with the anaconda ecosystem as a whole

Comment: Indeed, why use `venv` when conda has all the same functionality (and more!) built in?

Comment: Thanks, I used conda and it is fine except each time I create a new venv using 
`$ conda create -n myvenv python` 
it starts downloading and installing python 3.6. I want to stick to python 3.5.2 to avoid conflicts installing OpenCV 3.2.0

Comment: I managed to stick to python 3.5.2 by doing:
`$ conda create -n myvenv python=3.5.2`
My problem is solved.